# MySQL Query - One Entry per Item in Last Six Hours

Tags: mysql

I have a table with hotel check-in dates and prices with timestamps.  I'm trying to figure out how to write a query that will select the most recently added item per checkin date, for each hotel, as long as it is in the last six hours.

Example table -

| Property | CheckIn | Price | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| HotelA | 2022-03-27 | $69.99 | 2022-03-27 05:44:18 |
| HotelB | 2022-03-27 | $79.99 | 2022-03-27 05:44:11 |
| HotelC | 2022-03-27 | $75.99 | 2022-03-27 05:44:15 |
| HotelA | 2022-03-28 | $65.99 | 2022-03-27 05:44:18 |
| HotelB | 2022-03-28 | $77.99 | 2022-03-27 05:44:21 |
| HotelC | 2022-03-28 | $79.99 | 2022-03-27 05:44:25 |
| HotelA | 2022-03-29 | $63.99 | 2022-03-27 05:44:27 |
| HotelB | 2022-03-29 | $75.99 | 2022-03-27 05:44:31 |
| HotelC | 2022-03-29 | $77.99 | 2022-03-27 05:44:33 |
| HotelA | 2022-03-27 | $35.99 | 2022-03-27 05:54:05 |
| HotelB | 2022-03-27 | $40.99 | 2022-03-27 05:54:08 |
| HotelC | 2022-03-27 | $45.99 | 2022-03-27 05:54:11 |
| HotelA | 2022-03-28 | $47.99 | 2022-03-27 05:54:15 |
| HotelB | 2022-03-28 | $49.99 | 2022-03-27 05:54:18 |
| HotelC | 2022-03-28 | $51.99 | 2022-03-27 05:54:21 |

As you can see in the example table, there are multiple entries for HotelA for example, with a CheckIn on 2022-03-27.  I just want the most recent one ($35.99).

I have tried using GROUP BY, but MySQL keeps telling me that I'm violating "only_full_group_by" mode unless I group by CheckIn, Price, and timestamp, which doesn't work, it displays all the values in the example table above.

To return results from the last 6 hours I'm using **`"WHERE timestamp \>= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 6 HOUR)"`** in the select statement, which does seem to work!

**`DISTINCT`** doesn't seem to work because each row is distinct.

Not sure what to try next.

Here's what I would like the statement to return based on the example table above -

| Property | CheckIn | Price | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| HotelA | 2022-03-29 | $63.99 | 2022-03-27 05:44:27 |
| HotelB | 2022-03-29 | $75.99 | 2022-03-27 05:44:31 |
| HotelC | 2022-03-29 | $77.99 | 2022-03-27 05:44:33 |
| HotelA | 2022-03-27 | $35.99 | 2022-03-27 05:54:05 |
| HotelB | 2022-03-27 | $40.99 | 2022-03-27 05:54:08 |
| HotelC | 2022-03-27 | $45.99 | 2022-03-27 05:54:11 |
| HotelA | 2022-03-28 | $47.99 | 2022-03-27 05:54:15 |
| HotelB | 2022-03-28 | $49.99 | 2022-03-27 05:54:18 |
| HotelC | 2022-03-28 | $51.99 | 2022-03-27 05:54:21 |

If the timestamp column is missing from the output results that's fine too, as long as the rest of the data the query outputs is grouped properly.  I'm most interested in the Property, CheckIn, and Price column.

The suggested answer is not working.  They are manually entering the group names (which are actually numbers).  There are hundreds of properties, which would take hours to manually list.  Additionally the list would have to be maintained, which would take extra time.

Comment: By date last 6 hours is that between 18:00 and 23:59 every day except today or the last 6 hours of today and the last (6:00 - time now) of yesterday if we are before 6:00?

Comment: Note: "If the timestamp column is missing from the result set"  If the timestamp is missing, then it will never be in the last six hours, so it will be ignored?

Comment: @Kendle - Last 6 hrs from the current time.  If it's 8AM, then 2-8AM.

Comment: @Luuk - I meant to say the timestamp column doesn't necessarily have to be displayed in the results, if there is some query that performs this task, but doesn't output the timestamp column.

Comment: @Kendle - That does not answer the question.  They are manually entering the group.  I would have to manually enter each hotel name, which there are hundreds!

Comment: I have no idea why @javier damaged your question by changing `>=` to `\>=`.  The duplicate seems appropriate to me.  There are probably more.  If not, please create a db-fiddle that shows your implementation of the advice (and the failure).